# How to setup the execution environment for the 'Play' button in VS-code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, execution, working-directory

I have no idea why the execution is perfectly find when using 'Run Without Debugging' & 'Start Debugging' but the environment is not the same when pressing the 'Play' button below, it will error

[image]

How can I set the environment for the upon button so that all the executions are running under the same directory.

Thanks.

Comment: that button is not connected to the `launch.json` file it just types a command in the terminal to run the current script. Setup a working `launch.json` and always use F5 or the button in the Run/Debug bar

Comment: @Woody -What kind of path do you want to set it to? When you click the run button, what error does the terminal display?